# Mule Web Service Consumer not loading WSDL

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-esb

I am trying to load WSDL using mule's Web Service Consumer but no success. If I try same WSDL from SOAPUI it works without running into any issues.

I tried below 2 options and both directing me to different issues. Any suggestion?

**Option#1.** Tried to load WSDL with URL gives me PKIX path building failed as below

[image]

**Option#2.** Also, tried to load WSDL as resource i.e. by saving it into src/main/resources folder. This gives me below

[image]

NOTE: I am using Anypoint Studio 6.4.4 with mule **Community Edition** 3.9 and JDK 1.8.

**WSDL:** https://esweb.revenue.louisiana.gov/fsettest/fsetgatewaywebservice.asmx?wsdl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the wsdl certificate to Java cacerts keystore. Here you have a useful link:

https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO4085.html

On the other hand, you are getting the second error, because that wsdl you downloaded has an import of another wsdl (this is the other wsdl http://esweb.revenue.louisiana.gov/fsettest/fsetgatewaywebservice.asmx?wsdl=wsdl1). 
If you want to do it this way (that I would not recommend), you will need to download all the wsdls that are imported, and reference them locally.

Comment: Due to requirement I have to choose option#2 hence I downloaded required resources which solved my problem to connect to the Web Service. Thanks for suggestion!